# How to save features into a file in keras?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have trained weight matrix, I would like to extract features at each end every layer and store them in a file. How could I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer)

> One simple way is to create a new Model that will output the layers
>   that you are interested in:
>
> ```
> from keras.models import Model
> model = ...  # create the original model 
> layer_name = 'my_layer' 
> intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
>                            outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)    
> intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can build a Keras function that will return the
>   output of a certain layer given a certain input, for example:
>
> ```
> from keras import backend as K
> get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
>                               [model.layers[3].output])
> layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X])[0]
> ```
>
> Similarly, you could build a Theano and TensorFlow function directly.
>
> Note that if your model has a different behavior in training and
>   testing phase (e.g. if it uses Dropout,  BatchNormalization, etc.),
>   you will need to pass the learning phase flag to your function:
>
> ```
> get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
>                               [model.layers[3].output])
>
> # output in test mode = 0
> layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X, 0])[0]
>
> # output in train mode = 1
> layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X, 1])[0]
> ```

Then you just need to store your predictions in a file using e.g. `np.save('filename.npz',intermediate_output )`